# DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK doesn't work when loading external HTML via HTTP?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I need to process onclick event for A element in CDhtmlDialog that loads external HTML file with HTTP protocol (not HTML from resource). I use following code:

```
BEGIN_DHTML_EVENT_MAP(CAdDialog)
    DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK(_T("adlink"), OnAnchorClicked)
END_DHTML_EVENT_MAP()
```

My A element HTML follows:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="adlink">Click here!!!</a>
```

I expect that CDhtmlDialog will call OnAnchorClicked function when user clicks the link. However, nothing happens instead. It looks like DHTML_EVENT_ONCLICK doesn't work for CDhtmlDialog if it loads external URL instead of loading resource? Is there any way to catch onclick event for HTML loaded via HTTP in CDhtmlDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DHTML_EVENT_TAG(DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS_ONCLICK, _T("a"), OnLinkClickedMethod)
```

That was a real pain to find. Microsoft's documentation for the dispatch id's is awful. That will catch every link clicked, ever, in your CDHtmlDialog.

A note to all future wayward travelers: All dispatch ID's are in the MsHtmdid.h header file.